# Downloading a video from youtube and convert to MP4

Tags: python, ffmpeg, youtube-dl

I created a script to download a youtube video and extract an images from it for each period

**screenshotvideo**

```
def screenshotvideo(url, interval, id, fullduration, title, quality):
    interval = int(interval)
    parsed_t = isodate.parse_duration(fullduration)
    durationseconds=parsed_t.total_seconds()
    iterat=int(durationseconds/int(interval))
    for i in range(0, iterat):
        print(str(id))
        print(str(i))
        print(str(i*interval))
        part(url, time.strftime('%H:%M:%S', time.gmtime(int(i*interval))), "00:00:01", title+"-"+str(id), quality)
```

**part**

```
def part(url, starttime, duration, name, quality):
    f = os.popen("ffmpeg $(youtube-dl -f "+quality+" -g '"+url+"' | sed 's/.*/-ss "+starttime+" -i &/') -t "+duration+" -c copy "+name+".mp4")
    now = f.read()
    print(now)
    f = os.popen("ffmpeg -i "+name+".mp4 -ss 00:00:00 -vframes 1 "+name+".jpg")
    now = f.read()
    print(now)
    f = os.popen("rm -rf "+name+".mp4")
    now = f.read()
    print(now)
```

so i got the folowing error in the first `ffmpeg` command

> [mp4 @ 0x55d537f64240] Could not find tag for codec vp8 in stream #0, codec not currently supported in container.
>
> Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument

Comment: FYI most YouTube videos are available in MP4 format already anyway - you shouldn't have to do any conversion in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is close to [szatmary answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55342791/downloading-a-video-from-youtube-and-convert-to-mp4/55343900#55343900) but i need to download video in mp4 format, so all i neet to do is to edit the first command

```
ffmpeg $(youtube-dl -f "+quality+" -g '"+url+"' | sed 's/.*/-ss "+starttime+" -i &/') -t "+duration+" -c:v libx264 "+name+".mp4
```

after that i got other error for the images file name that i want to saved each time from the video.

So this is the final solution i found:

```
def screenshotvideo(url, interval, id, fullduration, title, quality):
    interval = int(interval)
    parsed_t = isodate.parse_duration(fullduration)
    durationseconds=parsed_t.total_seconds()
    iterat=int(durationseconds/int(interval))
    for i in range(0, iterat):
        print(str(id))
        print(str(i))
        print(str(i*interval))
        part(url, time.strftime('%H:%M:%S', time.gmtime(int(i*interval))), "00:00:01", title+"-"+str(id), quality, i)


def part(url, starttime, duration, name, quality, i):
    f = os.popen("ffmpeg $(youtube-dl -f "+quality+" -g '"+url+"' | sed 's/.*/-ss "+starttime+" -i &/') -t "+duration+" -c:v libx264 "+name+".mp4")
    now = f.read()
    print(now)
    f = os.popen("ffmpeg -i "+name+".mp4 -ss 00:00:00 -vframes 1 "+name+"_"+str(i)+".jpg")
    now = f.read()
    print(now)
    f = os.popen("rm -rf "+name+".mp4")
    now = f.read()
    print(now)
```

Answer (score 5):

The error is pretty clear:

> codec not currently supported in container.

Use a different container that supports vp8, like webm or mkv.